# thymeleaf layout:decorate seems not be working as expected

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-boot-maven-plugin

i have a thymeleaf project but am getting issues using the layout:decorate as am not getting the expected output. i have viewed the previous stackoverflow posts and they did not help. Here is what i have done. i need some help as i don't know what went wrong.

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.2.2</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
    <thymeleaf.version>3.0.9.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
</properties>
```

**header.html**

```
   <header th:fragment="header">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Log in</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
      </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Users</a>
      </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="hidden"/>
      <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Logout</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

</header>
```

**footer.html**

```
   <div th:fragment="footer">

    <p>
    &copy; 2018 Collinewait
    </p>

</div>
```

**main_layout.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../static/css/style.css" th:href="@{css/style.css}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../static/css/materia/bootstrap.min.css" th:href="@{css/materia/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
<script th:src="@{webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{webjars/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div th:replace="fragments/header::header"></div>

    <div layout:fragment="content">

    </div>

    <div th:replace="fragments/footer::footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http:www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
    layout:decorate="~{fragments/main_layout}">
<head>

</head>
<body>

    <div layout:fragment="content" class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <p>Hello its Colline wait</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

it only displays: Hello its Colline wait. without header and footer.

resources are structured like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWjlP.png)
. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

try to change this dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-layout-dialect -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

by

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.zhanhb</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

this works for me